# Material ui autocomplete - conditional noOptionsText

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I am using material ui autocomplete in my project.

The option list is empty initially and on input change, the list will be populated. So during the initial empty state, i need to show the placeholder "Type to search".

[image]

This can be achieved with the property

```
noOptionsText="Type to search"
```

The issue is that on input change and when there are no results, it still shows "Type to search" instead of "No Results". So basically there are two things needed.

- Show "Type to search" in the options area initially (currently achieved using noOptionsText)
- Show "No Results" when the search result is empty.

Any idea on how to achieve this

Comment: Hey, i think the sandbox here achieved the same thing: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vigorous-meadow-dsdlm5. It keeps the input value as react state. Any reason it didn't work? I replied in your previous question too.

Comment: Yep, this is what i needed. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Material ui autocomplete - empty placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77603825/material-ui-autocomplete-empty-placeholder)